# Store photo url in database

Tags: node.js, json, reactjs, facebook-login

I am using Facebook API for login in my react app. Frontend is reactJS and backend is nodeJS. 
On first login I'm sending name, email and profile photo url to nodeJS. Prolem is that the nodeJS doesn't parse the url in proper way, even though it was sent properly form reactJS (using POST).

It looks like this:

```
{'{"name":"testname","email":"test@mail.com","profilePhoto":"https://platform-lookaside.fbsbx.com/platform/profilepic/?asid': '1111111111111111', height: '50', width: '50', ext: '1111111111', hash: 'AeRNlZmAF4w5mT5r"}' }
```

Should look like this:

```
{"name":"testname","email":"test@mail.com","profilePhoto":"https://platform-lookaside.fbsbx.com/platform/profilepic/?asid=1111111111111111&height=50&width=50&ext=1111111111&hash=ArS0tErHD8Tg9l3s"}"
```

So in other words it shouldn't split the url to parts, because i want to have the original url in database.

Here is the server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const config = require("../config");
const knex = require("../knex/knex");
const api = require("./api");
const cors = require("cors");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
  );
  next();
});

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use("/api", api.router);

app.listen(config.port, config.host, () => {
  console.log(Server is running on http://${config.host}:${config.port});
});
```

and this is apiRequest.js in reactJS:

```
const apiRequest = (apiPath, options) => {
  const mainOptions = {
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json"
    },
    mode: "cors",
    credentials: "include"
  };

  const finalOptions = merge(mainOptions, options);

  if (finalOptions.body) {
    finalOptions.body = JSON.stringify(finalOptions.body);
    finalOptions.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
  }

  const requestUrl = `http://${backendConfig.host}:${
    backendConfig.port
  }/api/${apiPath}`;
  console.log(requestUrl, finalOptions);
  return fetch(requestUrl, finalOptions).then(response =>
    solveErrors(response)
  );
};
```

Is this approach good or is there a better way to store url in database?

Comment: The problem is most likely on the clientside with how your forming your `finalOptions.body`. Can you show a `console.log(finalOptions)` output? An alternative (and easier approach) would be to use `axios`: https://github.com/axios/axios instead of `fetch`. Axios automatically handles the XHR structure.

Comment: @MattCarlotta It logs JSON body: {"name":"testname","email":"test@mail.com","profilePhoto":"https://platform-lookaside.fbsbx.com/platform/profilepic/?asid=1111111111111111&height=50&width=50&ext=1111111111&hash=ArS0tErHD8Tg9l3s"}"}
credentials:
"include"
headers
:
{Accept: "application/json", Content-Type: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
method
:
"POST"
mode
:
"cors"
_proto_
:
Object

Comment: Without a replicable example and being able to test it myself, try changing `bodyParser` options: `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));`. If that doesn't work, send me a repo link so I can run it locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it!

I removed `credentials: "include"` and changed `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` to `"application/json"`